# How to use routerlink in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to redirect from one page to another using routerlink and I had tried the following code,

I have the following route as my url

```
http://localhost:3000/#/app/dashboard
```

I want to redirect to this,when i click on this

```
  [routerLink]=" ['tables/basic'] "

http://localhost:3000/#/app/tables/basic
```

but it is going to

```
http://localhost:3000/#/app/dashboard/tables/basic
```

Here dashboard should be removed and how can I do that? Can anyone pls provide some help?

my routes.ts,

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';


export const ROUTES: Routes = [{
   path: '', redirectTo: 'app', pathMatch: 'full'
  }, {
    path: 'app',   loadChildren: () => System.import('./layout/layout.module')
  }, {
    path: 'login', loadChildren: () => System.import('./login/login.module')
  }, {
    path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent
  }, {
    path: '**',    component: ErrorComponent
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

```
[routerLink]="['../tables/basic']"
```

or

```
[routerLink]="['/app/tables/basic']"
```

To be sure you would need to provide the information what routes your application has configured and what component contains the `[routerLink]`

Comment: This one worked 

[routerLink]="['/app/tables/basic']"

Answer (score 0):

if you want to route from button click you can easily use this, and also you can use it as a parameter parser through the components.firstly i will describe how to use it as a only for routing.

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/user/complain']">complain</a>
```

from above example we can route the **user/complain** using **complain**  tag

now i am going to describe the second one(how to parse the parameters through the components)

i will do it using the router params

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user/complain', job.id]">complain</a>
```

from that we can parse **job.id** to complain component.

in complain component.ts file -

```
export class ComplainComponent {

  id: number;
  private sub: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number


   });

  }

}
```

we can assign a variable for router parameter in this file.then you can easily whether is it worked or not by complain component.html file by

```
<h3>{{job.id}}</h3>
```